# How can I prevent myself from getting stressed during gameplay in video games?

Tags: health

Whenever I get in a dangerous place or run into a dangerous enemy in a game, I just get pumped full of adrenaline and freaked out and it both makes me play worse and just doesn't feel good, it's not that far off from a panic attack, how can I stop getting freaked out? notable freak-outs include:

- the nether: DANGEROUS
- Soul twisters (Hollow Knight)
- bosses in anything
- super dangerous places in anything (especially when I'm low on HP), especially the Ooma and fog canyon in hollow knight (until I can stop psyching myself out, GOD that game is terrible for my nerves)
- Any ganon or divine beast in BOTW
- tererria in general, especially a lot of the music. This is a big one because it is SUCH a great game and I can't play it without freaking out.
  You get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plarium](https://plarium.com/en/blog/deal-with-gamer-rage/) says that you should rest from it once in a while.

Stress from video games as common as it is on the internet, has many websites representing how to deal with it. Here is a list:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/I-get-outrageously-mad-at-video-games-to-the-point-of-hitting-myself-Why)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/truegaming/comments/1xh6nw/any_tips_to_stop_getting_angry_at_video_games/)
- [Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Over-Anger-Caused-by-Video-Games)
- [Medium](https://pattheflip.medium.com/how-can-i-curb-my-anger-in-fighting-games-35fdec838ec6)
- [The Gamer](https://www.thegamer.com/how-to-control-gamer-rage-in-yourself-loved-ones/)

etc.

---

1/3 of websites call it "Gamer Rage" and so it gets the definition of frustration of games and that, and my recommendation from Plarium overall, if you love playing games, is that you should lower the difficulty (I don't understand why Minecraft is part of your tags' list of anger) of the game. For Minecraft, you can do normal mode. If you don't like playing games very often, you should focus the anger on something useless...

If your anger is still present after this, pour water on your head or drink coffee (notice that it is just a game), and keep playing if desired, note that nobody is perfect in anything, so you should just try your best to not freak out.

Comment: Why would you pour water on your head?

Comment: I meant noticing it's a game, like to sharpen up. @OKprogrammer

Comment: Ok. That makes a bit more sense.